# I am trying to understand how sets are generally defined using ZF set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms

I've been reading about ZF set theory.  Using the book, *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech it starts with these axioms (informal definitions here).

Axiom of Existence: There exists a set which has no elements.

Axiom of Extensionality: If two sets contain the same elements they are equal.

Axiom Schema of Comprehension: Let $S,T$ be sets. Let $x$ be an object and $P$ be a property of $x$. Then for any set $T$ there exists a set $S$ such that $x ∈ S$ if and only if $x ∈ T$ and $P$ is true.

Axiom of Pair: Given any two sets $x$ and $y$ there exists a set $S$ such that $x,y ∈ S$.

Axiom of Union: Given a set $S$ there exists a set $T$ such that $x ∈ T$ if an only if $x ∈ X$ for some $X ∈ S$.

At this point I am curious how ZF actually gets sets that are not based off the empty set.  That is, we know the empty set exists by the Axiom of Existence so we can have two sets $A = \emptyset, B=\emptyset$.  By the Axiom of Pair we can have set $C = \{A, B\} = \{\emptyset, \emptyset \}$.  However, how would we get a set such as $D=\{\text{Apple}, \text{Pear}\}$.

Would we have to use the Axiom Schema of Replacement to actually bring this set into existence?  This would allow us to create a mapping between the sets C and D.

Comment: The axiom of pairing and union is not a schema: it is just a single sentence, not a family of sentences as the schema of separation and replacement are.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  My fault for copying the line above.  I will edit the question.

Comment: I believe it is consistent with ZF that all sets **are** "based off the empty set"; perhaps someone who knows better than me about these things will weigh in. But I do have to ask: How do you know an apple is not based off the empty set?

Comment: There is a difference between sets that MUST exist in any model of the axioms (these are the sets you [can get from the empty set using the axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe)) and sets that CAN exist in some model of the axioms (the example you gave).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Excellent comment!  Can you comment on my use of the Axiom of Replacement here?  That is, we know set C MUST exist in the model and using the Axiom of Replacement we can show that set D CAN exist.  Is this the correct notion?

Comment: I think what you need is to already have (in your model) at least one set containing *Apple* and at least one set containing *Pear* to obtain a set containing both (and no other elements). As for what axioms you'd use, and the procedure for applying them, this would depend on the nature of the set(s) that have those elements. For example, if you already have $\{Apple\}$ and $\{Pear\},$ then you can just form the union. Otherwise, you'll probably need to obtain these singleton sets first. Or, if you have for example $\{Apple, \, Pear, \, x\},$ then the subset axiom will get your set.

Comment: @LeeMosher It's not only *consistent* that all sets are "based off the emptyset," it's *provable*: every set is an element of some iterated powerset starting from the emptyset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathsf{ZF}$, and its many variants, describes what may at first appear to be a quite *limited* mathematical universe. Most obviously, the axiom of **Extensionality** says that every object is determined entirely by its elements. In particular, this rules out *urelements* or *atoms* - objects which don't have any elements, but aren't $\emptyset$. Presumably this includes things like "Apple," within which $\in$ plays no role.

However, much more is true. In a precise sense, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that everything is "built from" the emptyset: via **Foundation** and **Replacement**, everything is in some (possibly transfinitely) iterated powerset of $\emptyset$. Phrasing this precisely requires us to first develop the basic theory of *ordinals*, which is nontrivial so I'm skipping it in the interests of brevity, but the basic idea is just that according to the $\mathsf{ZF}$-axioms, everything  looks like nested curly braces.

This may seem to contradict the standard maxim that $\mathsf{ZF}$ can implement all of mathematics: where, for example, is $17$ in a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$? The key here is the word "implement." Basically, you should think of the $\mathsf{ZF}$ axioms as describing a context which is "ontologically narrow" in the sense that there is really only one type of thing, yet surprisingly expressively powerful. For example, the standard implementation of the natural numbers in set theory is via the **finite ordinals**:

- An ordinal is defined as a hereditarily transitive set, and the successor of an ordinal $\alpha$ is defined to be $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$.
- An ordinal is finite iff it is an element of the smallest ordinal which is itself closed under successor (intuitively, this is the first infinite ordinal $\omega$).
- Addition and multiplication of ordinals can be defined by transfinite recursion; on the finite ordinals, this winds up producing a copy of $\mathbb{N}$.

Basically, rich non-set-flavored structures enter the $\mathsf{ZF}$-world by coding procedures which are often tedious and annoying but get the job done. One "Platonist fable" we might tell at this point is the following:

> Within the whole mathematical universe, there is a particular region $V$ consisting of the "pure sets" - basically, all the stuff we can build from $\emptyset$ via a few simple set-theoretic operations. The collection $V$ of pure sets considered on its own satisfies $\mathsf{ZF}$. While there may well be lots of mathematical objects not in $V$, everything in the mathematical universe *can* be "faithfully copied into" $V$ - so if you understand all of $V$, you understand everything.

While there's a lot to object to in the above, I think it may help clarify why $(i)$ $\mathsf{ZF}$ seems to say things we naively think of as false yet $(ii)$ that's not particularly worrying.

Answer (score 1):

ZF set theory is a theory that deals with sets that are determined by their members: the axiom of existentiality states that $A = B \Leftrightarrow (\forall x((x \in A) \Leftrightarrow (x \in B)))$. The axiom of replacement only helps to construct sets with a great number of members and doesn't produce any objects that aren't sets. If you want to have objects that aren't sets, then you need to change the ZF axioms to admit what are known as ur-elements: objects with no members that are distinct from the empty set.  For your apples and pears, it is probably simpler to stick with ZF and use an encoding: $\mathit{Apple} = 0$ and $\mathit{Pear} = 1$, where $0$ and $1$ are defined in the usual way (as $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\})$.